# how to add geocordination map to form with here api

Tags: javascript, forms, here-api

i try to add  map to my form  to get the geocordination  of a place that user select  by drag  marker itry to add  input to get  Geocoding Autocomplete and  get  the suggested  place  and edit it with drag the map to the exact place to get  the lng and lat of this place

i tried  with  an input to  add closet address  and edit it with the dragen marker

```
          <div id="map" style="position:absolute; width:49%; height:100%; background:grey" ></div>
          <div id="panel" style="position:absolute; width:49%; left:51%; height:100%; background:inherit" ></div>
          <input id='lat'  type='hidden' name='lat' >
          <input id='lng'  type='hidden' name='lng' >
          <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >

          var AUTOCOMPLETION_URL = 'https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json',
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            query = '';

        /**
         * If the text in the text box  has changed, and is not empty,
         * send a geocoding auto-completion request to the server.
         *
         * @param {Object} textBox the textBox DOM object linked to this event
         * @param {Object} event the DOM event which fired this listener
         */
        function autoCompleteListener(textBox, event) {

          if (query != textBox.value){
            if (textBox.value.length >= 1){

              /**
              * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Geocoder Autocompletion
              * API documentation.
              *
              */
              var params = '?' +
                'query=' +  encodeURIComponent(textBox.value) +   // The search text which is the basis of the query
                '&beginHighlight=' + encodeURIComponent('<mark>') + //  Mark the beginning of the match in a token. 
                '&endHighlight=' + encodeURIComponent('</mark>') + //  Mark the end of the match in a token. 
                '&maxresults=1' +  // The upper limit the for number of suggestions to be included 
                                  // in the response.  Default is set to 5.
                '&app_id=' + APPLICATION_ID +
                '&app_code=' + APPLICATION_CODE;
              ajaxRequest.open('GET', AUTOCOMPLETION_URL + params );
              ajaxRequest.send();
            }
          }
          query = textBox.value;
        }


        /**
         *  This is the event listener which processes the XMLHttpRequest response returned from the server.
         */
        function onAutoCompleteSuccess() {
         /*
          * The styling of the suggestions response on the map is entirely under the developer's control.
          * A representitive styling can be found the full JS + HTML code of this example
          * in the functions below:
          */
          clearOldSuggestions();
          addSuggestionsToPanel(this.response);  // In this context, 'this' means the XMLHttpRequest itself.
          addSuggestionsToMap(this.response);
        }


        /**
         * This function will be called if a communication error occurs during the XMLHttpRequest
         */
        function onAutoCompleteFailed() {
          alert('Ooops!');
        }

        // Attach the event listeners to the XMLHttpRequest object
        ajaxRequest.addEventListener("load", onAutoCompleteSuccess);
        ajaxRequest.addEventListener("error", onAutoCompleteFailed);
        ajaxRequest.responseType = "json";


        /**
         * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
         */


        // set up containers for the map  + panel
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
          suggestionsContainer = document.getElementById('panel');

        //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
        var APPLICATION_ID = '9aZpIUD2ZlcwJ7XXD06p',
          APPLICATION_CODE = 'qRg4JPs_5dJ6I1j16rbCuQ';

        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
          app_id: APPLICATION_ID,
          app_code: APPLICATION_CODE,
          useCIT: false,
          useHTTPS: true
        });
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();
        var group = new H.map.Group();

        group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
          map.setCenter(evt.target.getPosition());
          openBubble(
             evt.target.getPosition(), evt.target.getData());
        }, false);


        //Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
        var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
          defaultLayers.normal.map,{
          center: {lat:52.5160, lng:13.3779},
          zoom: 3
        });

         map.addObject(group);

        //Step 3: make the map interactive
        // MapEvents enables the event system
        // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

        // Create the default UI components
        var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

        // Hold a reference to any infobubble opened
        var bubble;

        /**
         * Function to Open/Close an infobubble on the map.
         * @param  {H.geo.Point} position     The location on the map.
         * @param  {String} text              The contents of the infobubble.
         */
        function openBubble(position, text){
         if(!bubble){
            bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(
              position,
              // The FO property holds the province name.
              {content: '<small>' + text+ '</small>'});
            ui.addBubble(bubble);
          } else {
            bubble.setPosition(position);
            bubble.setContent('<small>' + text+ '</small>');
            bubble.open();
          }
        }


        /**
         * The Geocoder Autocomplete API response retrieves a complete addresses and a `locationId`.
         * for each suggestion.
         *
         * You can subsequently use the Geocoder API to geocode the address based on the ID and 
         * thus obtain the geographic coordinates of the address.
         *
         * For demonstration purposes only, this function makes a geocoding request
         * for every `locationId` found in the array of suggestions and displays it on the map.
         * 
         * A more typical use-case would only make a single geocoding request - for example
         * when the user has selected a single suggestion from a list.
         *
         * @param {Object} response
         */
        function addSuggestionsToMap(response){
          /**
           * This function will be called once the Geocoder REST API provides a response
           * @param  {Object} result          A JSONP object representing the  location(s) found.
           */
          var onGeocodeSuccess = function (result) {
            var marker,
              locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
              i;

              // Add a marker for each location found
              for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new H.map.Marker({
                  lat : locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
                  lng : locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
                });
                marker.draggable = true;
          map.addObject(marker);
          map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
              behavior.disable();
            }
          }, false);
          map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
              behavior.disable();
          document.getElementById('lat').value = target['b']['lat'];
          document.getElementById('lng').value = target['b']['lng'];
        document.getElementById("map-feedback").style["boxShadow"] = "0 1px 10px 1px rgba(49, 113, 99, 0.9)";
            }    
          }, false);

           map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target,
                pointer = ev.currentPointer;
            if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
              target.setPosition(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY));
            }
          }, false);
                marker.setData(locations[i].Location.Address.Label);
                group.addObject(marker);

              }

              map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());

              if(group.getObjects().length < 2){
                map.setZoom(15);
              }
            },
            /**
             * This function will be called if a communication error occurs during the JSON-P request
             * @param  {Object} error  The error message received.
             */
            onGeocodeError = function (error) {
              alert('Ooops!');
            },
             /**
             * This function uses the geocoder service to calculate and display information
             * about a location based on its unique `locationId`.
             *
             * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Geocoder API documentation.
             * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-search.html
             *
             * @param {string} locationId    The id assigned to a given location
             */
            geocodeByLocationId = function (locationId) {
              geocodingParameters = {
                locationId : locationId
              };

              geocoder.geocode(
                geocodingParameters,
                onGeocodeSuccess,
                onGeocodeError
              );
            }

          /* 
           * Loop through all the geocoding suggestions and make a request to the geocoder service
           * to find out more information about them.
           */

          response.suggestions.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            geocodeByLocationId(item.locationId);
          });
        }


        /**
         * Removes all H.map.Marker points from the map and adds closes the info bubble
         */
        function clearOldSuggestions(){
           group.removeAll ();
            if(bubble){
              bubble.close();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Format the geocoding autocompletion repsonse object's data for display
         *
         * @param {Object} response
         */
        function addSuggestionsToPanel(response){
           var suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions');
           suggestions.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response, null, ' ');
        }



         var content =  '<strong style="font-size: large;">' + 'Geocoding Autocomplete'  + '</strong></br>';

          content  += '<br/><input type="text" id="auto-complete" style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; min-width:90%"  onkeyup="return autoCompleteListener(this, event);"><br/>';
          content  += '<br/><strong>Response:</strong><br/>';
          content  += '<div style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%;"><pre style="max-height:235px"><code  id="suggestions" style="font-size: small;">' +'{}' + '</code></pre></div>';

          suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = content;
          </script>
```

but what i get is when  i get  suggested point and try to drag it but the mouse  don't leave  the marker

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the browser console because the user is trying to execute this line of code on "dragend" event:

document.getElementById("map-feedback").style["boxShadow"] = "0 1px 10px 1px rgba(49, 113, 99, 0.9)";

but "map-feedback" element doesn't present on the page.

If you comment out this line, the marker becomes properly draggable.